# Iterating collection and trying to get reference field inside documents .get() is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I am trying to get a collection then iterating over its documents. inside every document there's a reference field for another collection document. Normally if i query for it then there is no problem but iterating creates a problem

Following the field i want to get while iterating over organization-members

[image]

```
 const result = await firestore.collection("organization-members").get();
      result.docs.forEach((doc) => {  // or result.forEach
        const data = doc.data();
        const organization = data.organization;
     
        const orgData = await organization.get() // But this says that organization.get() is not a function
      });
```

However if i hard query then it works okay

```
const snap = await firestore
      .doc("organization-members/BOcSNLR4bt8i0Ay4aAr7")
      .get();
    const orgSnap = await snap.data().organization.get();
    console.log(orgSnap.data());
```

There objects are different as well

upper log is from when i hard query for it and the lower one when i loop through the collection documents

[image]

What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having similar problem this answer might help you

So first of all there was a mistake inside my code but that gave me another answer

Mistake is is that i forgot to add async in forEach function

This should be like this

```
 const result = await firestore.collection("organization-members").get();
  result.docs.forEach(async (doc) => {  // or result.forEach
    const data = doc.data();
    const organization = data.organization;
 
    const orgData = await organization.get() // But this says that organization.get() is not a function
  });
```

But this is not the correct way

Apparently async/await does not work properly inside forEach loop i don't know the reason behind this i did contact the firebase team and there representative said the same thing so the best way should be to use **for loop**

e.g

```
for(doc of result.docs)
```

This will always work fine