# How can I decrement a field value from firestore after submitting a form successfully?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these collection of items from firestore:

- availability : true
- stocks: 100
- item: item1

[image]

I kind of wanted to decrement the stocks after submitting the form: I have these `where()` to compare if what the user chose is the same item from the one saved in the firestore.

```
  function incrementCounter(collref) {
    collref = firestore
      .collection("items")
      .doc()
      .where(selectedItem, "==", selectedItem);

    collref.update({
      stocks: firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });
  }
```

This is how I'll submit my form and I've set the `incrementCounter()` after saving it:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(id);
      const ref = userRef.set(
        {
         ....
          },
        },

        { merge: true }
      );

      console.log(" saved");
      incrementCounter();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

There's no error in submitting the form. However, the `incrementCounter()` is not working and displays this error:

```
TypeError: _Firebase_utils__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.firestore.collection(...).doc(...).where is not a function
```

Comment: I believe you are using FieldValue wrong. If your firestore variable is something like this ```const firestore = firebase.firestore()``` then you cannout use firestore in FieldValue of update section. You will have to use ```stocks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)```

Comment: @SulmanAzhar I'm still having the same error

Comment: Also confirm if `.where(selectedItem, "==", selectedItem)` is valid statement. For example, it's checking a field `itemName` has value `itemName`. Maybe share a screenshot of your document so we can confirm if that's what you need.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added a screenshot of the document. Thank you

Comment: @Jenn that seems to be another problem. If you are trying to decrement doc fields where item is `item1`, then change it to: `.where("item", "==", selectedItem)` Apart from that, other issues are mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where()` method exists on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) and not a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). You also need to get references to those documents first so first get all the matching documents and then update all of them using `Promise.all()` or `Batch Writes`:

```
function incrementCounter() {
  // not param required  ^^
  const collref = firestore
      .collection("items")
      // .doc() <-- remove this
      .where(selectedItem, "==", selectedItem);
      //      ^^^                 ^^^
      //      doc field           field value
      //      "item"              {selectedItemName}

  collRef.get().then(async (qSnap) => {
    const updates = []
    qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      updates.push(doc.ref.update({ stocks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) }))
    })
    await Promise.all(updates)
  })
}
```

If you are updating less than 500 documents, consider using batch writes to make sure all updates either fail or pass:

```js
collRef.get().then(async (qSnap) => {
  const batch = firestore.batch()

  qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.update(doc.ref, { stocks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) })
  })

  await batch.commit()
})
```

You can read more about batch writes in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#web-version-8_2)

Comment: Thank you. It did work and I also used the batch ones

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems here

1. There should be async-await for both functions
2. Your fieldValue should start from `firebase.firestore.FieldValue not firestoreFieldValue`
3. Also `where` clause is used for collection, not doc() so remove that as well. Also I don't think this will update the full collection but do check it and see. (The error you are getting is because of this)

I don't know how you are importing firebase in this application and I don't know how you have declared firestore but mostly firestore variable is declared like this

`const firestore = firebase.firestore();`

In here firestore is a function, not a property
But when you are using it in the `FieldValue` then it should be like

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),`

Notice that firestore here is a property not a function

Your full code should be like this

```
async function incrementCounter(collref) {
    collref = firestore
      .collection("items")
      .where(selectedItem, "==", selectedItem);

    const newRef = await collref.get();
    for(let i in newRef.docs){
      const doc = newRef.docs[i];
      await doc.update({
       stocks: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
     }); 
       // You can also batch this 
    }
  }



const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(id);
      const ref = await userRef.set(
        {
         ....
          },
        },

        { merge: true }
      );

      console.log(" saved");
      await incrementCounter();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Agreed that's why i added the comment of batch. Also ```forEach``` loops can cause some different problems as well that i once ran into. You can check that in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062793/iterating-collection-and-trying-to-get-reference-field-inside-documents-get-i